# Determinant of differential operator as exponential of Wess-Zumino-Witten action

Tags: conformal-field-theory, yang-mills, functional-determinants, wess-zumino-witten

I am currently reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9809087) (Mass Gap and Confinement in (2+1)-Dimensional Yang-Mills Theory, Dimitra Karabali) and between equations (6) and (7) the following identity is used:
\begin{equation*}
|\text{det}(D\overline{D})|=e^{2c_A \mathcal{S}(H)}.
\end{equation*}
Where $D=\partial-\partial MM^{-1}$, $\overline{D}=\overline{\partial}+{M^\dagger}^{-1} \overline{\partial} M^\dagger$, $c_A=N$ for $\text{SU}(N)$ and $\mathcal{S}(H)$ is the Wess-Zumino-Witten action of argument $M^\dagger M$. A paper I've found in the references (Goldstone fields in two dimensions with multivalued actions, A.M. Polyakov and P.B. Weigmann, Phys. Lett. B141 (1984) 233) is supposed to give an explanation for this equality but the differential operator $D\overline{D}$ is never used, the only equality that looks like the one I gave is for $\det(\gamma_\mu(\partial_\mu+A_\mu))$.

Does somebody have in mind how to prove this identity?

Comment: The formula is a bit problematic as the $| \ldots|$ indicate that that  $|Det(D\bar D)|$ is a real functional of $M$ while the CS action is complex.